# What exactly am I looking for to replace worn out bottom door seals?

Tags: insulation, doors, weatherstripping, air-sealing

I've got a sunroom of sorts that we use most of the year except winter, though it does have electric baseboard. It was built in the 80s I'm guessing and it looks like the door seals on the bottom of each door are probably original. Looking on the big box sites for door seals is simultaneously over and underwhelming because nothing seems to match exactly what I'm seeing here.

[image]

Of course right after posting I change my search phrasing and find this [sweep](https://www.lowes.com/pd/M-D-36-in-Beige-Door-Sweep/1148371?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_145_General-Hardware-_-1148371). Is this it?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: This is a double kerf door sweep, several options available from online sellers if you cannot sources it locally.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually proprietary, so you'd need to find one from the OEM or one that claims to be compatible, or you'd need to match some key attributes...

Most doors are 1-3/4" thick and either 32" or 36" wide, so you're mostly concerned with:

- Mounting rib spacing (they fit into the slots you see on the end)
- Bead or strip height (the space between the door itself and the threshold)
- Bead or strip *location*, as in where it engages with the threshold (probably less critical)

If you can match those up you're probably ok, though if you don't have an adjustable threshold your margin of error is small.

Helpful hint: Prolong the life of the new sweep by lubricating the threshold surface with something like silicone or Teflon. The high friction between rubber and wood can really tear things up.

If all that fails, you can probably find a nail-on one. Your door has a wooden core, so you can attach about anything that fits. Or use a draft stopper. Maybe you have an aunt who can knit you one.

Comment: Great idea with the teflon, never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the thing on the bottom of a door is known as a sweep.

Replacements are available; the hard part is getting one that fits into your door. Taking the old one with you to a good hardware store may help identify a match. There are also "generic" replacement sweeps that fit over the bottom of a door; there the question is whether there's enough clearance for the sweep you want to use.

People have been known to substitute homebrew solutions, especially for wooden doors; basically anything that provides a rain seal, fits between door and threshold, and won't wear out too quickly will do the job.